# I'm trying to create an onDimiss button in React js

Tags: reactjs

https://gist.github.com/justgoof9/7610432925d5f921dc745071d1d67657

So I made the onDismiss button but when I pass it on to the onClick in the Delete button it doesn't do anything. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
<IconButton aria-label="Delete" onClick={() => this.onDismiss() }>
```

You are creating an anonymous function that returns a onDismiss function, so when onClick is called due to a click, its only returning the function, not calling it.  BTW, creating anonymous functions inside renders is frowned upon consider refactoring it out to its own function

Comment: Oh my bad. But how would you make this work? For onClick i put {this.onDismiss}. For some reason it's not deleting the list.

Comment: you would call the function as i had in the code old - `<IconButton aria-label="Delete" onClick={() => this.onDismiss }>` / new - `<IconButton aria-label="Delete" onClick={() => this.onDismiss() }>`

Comment: you can also use `Array.filter` method to filter out the result that was click, it is much easier to read and use than cloning the list and `splicing` it

Comment: Ok, the issue is onDismiss is not a class method, you created it as a function outside of the class, remove the const and move it into the class method to use it

Comment: So I did the exact thing you said and I got this error : https://i.imgur.com/I1DtdOL.png

Comment: can you upload a new gist of the code? it just means that onDismiss is not defined properly within the class

Comment: The component you are calling onDismiss is not the component with state or that has onDismiss, you will have to do the same for all those functions so that they are all in scope or start passing onDismiss thru as a prop

Comment: Can you show me how you would do that? This is the part I'm confused with.